# php - how to extract values from array with string values with equal = sign without preg_match

Tags: php

I have received a response from server as a string, which I converted as array, but still I am not able to make out, how I can access values from this array like

`myarrray['txn_status'];`

as also from the string `clnt_rqst_meta`

```
array(13) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "txn_status=0399"
  [1]=>
  string(15) "txn_msg=failure"
  [2]=>
  string(55) "txn_err_msg=Transaction Cancelled : ERROR CODE TPPGE161"
  [3]=>
  string(17) "clnt_txn_ref=9178"
  [4]=>
  string(15) "tpsl_bank_cd=NA"
  [5]=>
  string(19) "tpsl_txn_id=T245107"
  [6]=>
  string(14) "txn_amt=121.00"
  [7]=>
  string(47) "clnt_rqst_meta={mob:9937253528}{custname:pawan}"
  [8]=>
  string(16) "tpsl_txn_time=NA"
  [9]=>
  string(15) "tpsl_rfnd_id=NA"
  [10]=>
  string(10) "bal_amt=NA"
  [11]=>
  string(47) "rqst_token=cd3f6f55-5990-4c3b-bb12-238eede827a0"
  [12]=>
  string(45) "hash=3cf25909ec73865d3200bc267119d3fcc21df463"
}
```

I know that the same can be achieved using regex/preg_match, but I am sure there must be some straight forward way to achieve it.

update: the actual string received from response is like this:

```
string(342) "txn_status=0399|txn_msg=failure|txn_err_msg=Transaction Cancelled : ERROR CODE TPPGE161|clnt_txn_ref=9178|tpsl_bank_cd=NA|tpsl_txn_id=T245107|txn_amt=121.00|clnt_rqst_meta={mob:9937253528}{custname:pawan}|tpsl_txn_time=NA|tpsl_rfnd_id=NA|bal_amt=NA|rqst_token=cd3f6f55-5990-4c3b-bb12-238eede827a0|hash=3cf25909ec73865d3200bc267119d3fcc21df463"
```

so I used `$response =explode("|",$response_str);`

Comment: I'd look at *how* you converted the response to an array in the first place, it looks as though you should have exploded values on `=` somewhere down the line to split keys from values.

Comment: explode() will probably be useful https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Hi Brett - I have updated my answer, as you can see, I have already used the explode.

Comment: use a second explode with ('=') as seperator, store element[0] as key, element[1] as value in a new array (basically FailedCoder answer)

Comment: ```foreach(explode("|",$str) as $foo){parse_str($foo,$tmp);$parsed=array_merge($parsed,$tmp);}var_dump($parsed['hash'],$parsed);```

Comment: This could almost be copied to Code Golf :) I got down to `$a=[];foreach(explode('|',$s)as$c){list($k,$v)=explode('=',$c);$a[$k]=$v;}` (74 characters - sloppy I know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could let the PHP function [`parse_str()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) do the heavy lifting for you but it expects to receive a standard query string, with the entries separated by `&`. Your input string uses a different separator (`|`) and `parse_str()` does not provide a way to tell it what character to use as separator.

The problem has a very simple solution: use [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace `|` to `&` in the input string then pass the result to `parse_str()`:

```
$input = 'txn_status=0399|txn_msg=failure|txn_err_msg=Transaction Cancelled : ERROR CODE TPPGE161|clnt_txn_ref=9178|tpsl_bank_cd=NA|tpsl_txn_id=T245107|txn_amt=121.00|clnt_rqst_meta={mob:9937253528}{custname:pawan}|tpsl_txn_time=NA|tpsl_rfnd_id=NA|bal_amt=NA|rqst_token=cd3f6f55-5990-4c3b-bb12-238eede827a0|hash=3cf25909ec73865d3200bc267119d3fcc21df463';
parse_str(str_replace('|', '&', $input), $output);

print_r($output);
```

It produces:

```
Array
(
    [txn_status] => 0399
    [txn_msg] => failure
    [txn_err_msg] => Transaction Cancelled : ERROR CODE TPPGE161
    [clnt_txn_ref] => 9178
    [tpsl_bank_cd] => NA
    [tpsl_txn_id] => T245107
    [txn_amt] => 121.00
    [clnt_rqst_meta] => {mob:9937253528}{custname:pawan}
    [tpsl_txn_time] => NA
    [tpsl_rfnd_id] => NA
    [bal_amt] => NA
    [rqst_token] => cd3f6f55-5990-4c3b-bb12-238eede827a0
    [hash] => 3cf25909ec73865d3200bc267119d3fcc21df463
)
```

See it in action: https://3v4l.org/KBaof

#### Warning

The solution exposed above works fine only if the input string does not contain `&` and `%`. These characters are special in query strings, `parse_str()` tries to interpret them using their special meaning and the code above breaks.

#### A solution that works when `&` or `%` is present in the input string

```
$input = 'txn_status=0399|txn_msg=failure|txn_err_msg=Transaction Cancelled : ERROR CODE TPPGE161|clnt_txn_ref=9178|tpsl_bank_cd=NA|tpsl_txn_id=T245107|txn_amt=121.00|clnt_rqst_meta={mob:9937253528}{custname:pawan}|tpsl_txn_time=NA|tpsl_rfnd_id=NA|bal_amt=NA|rqst_token=cd3f6f55-5990-4c3b-bb12-238eede827a0|hash=3cf25909ec73865d3200bc267119d3fcc21df463';
$output = array_reduce(
    explode('|', $input),
    function($acc, $item) {
        list($key, $value) = explode('=', $item, 2);
        $acc[$key] = $value;
        return $acc;
    },
    []
);

print_r($output);
```

It still fails if `|` is present in the values (e.g. `...|txn_err_msg=a|b|clnt_txn_ref=...`) but this issue doesn't have a solution because of the naive encoding of the input string.

If you can modify the server that produces the input data, change it to produce [JSON](https://json.org) output. JSON is a format that allows validation of the input string and PHP provides functions to [encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it. The code becomes cleaner on both sides.

Comment: Hi - Axiac, I think it is really straight forward and simple to understand. Thank you. can I also parse this string separately - `[clnt_rqst_meta] => {mob:9937253528}{custname:pawan}`

Comment: Works as long as the response never has URL characters in it, e.g. something like `[txn_msg] => bad & wrong` will completely break it as, technically, `parse_str()` is being used on something that's **not** an URL - this error cropped up in Magento 2.2 (fixed now), so I've seen it in the wild...

Comment: @Joshi, In *php.ini* file there is a setting named `magic_quotes_gpc`, and it affects the output of this function. If enabled, the variables are converted by addslashes() before parsed by parse_str().

Comment: @Kaz `magic_quotes_gpc` is [a thing of the past](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($myArray as $element) {
    $exploded = explode('=', $element);
    $newArray[$exploded[0]] = $exploded[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This any help?

```
$string = "txn_status=0399|txn_msg=failure|txn_err_msg=Transaction Cancelled : ERROR CODE TPPGE161|clnt_txn_ref=9178|tpsl_bank_cd=NA|tpsl_txn_id=T245107|txn_amt=121.00|clnt_rqst_meta={mob:9937253528}{custname:pawan}|tpsl_txn_time=NA|tpsl_rfnd_id=NA|bal_amt=NA|rqst_token=cd3f6f55-5990-4c3b-bb12-238eede827a0|hash=3cf25909ec73865d3200bc267119d3fcc21df463";
txn_status = ""; 
foreach(explode('|', $string) as $val){
    $temp = explode('=', $val);
    //$temp[0] is left side of =
    //$temp[1] is right side of =
    if($temp[0] == "txn_status"){
        txn_status = $temp[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you also can use sscanf. this is not regex but still using some pattern but is more clean than preg_match

```
$arr = ['key1=value1', 'key2=value2', 'key3=value3'];

foreach ($arr as $str) {
    sscanf($str, "%[^=]=%[^=]", $key, $value);
    echo "[$key => $value]";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that this expression might return the desired matches:

```
([^=]+)=([^=]+)(?:\||$)
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/([^=]+)=([^=]+)(?:\||$)/m';
$str = 'txn_status=0399|txn_msg=failure|txn_err_msg=Transaction Cancelled : ERROR CODE TPPGE161|clnt_txn_ref=9178|tpsl_bank_cd=NA|tpsl_txn_id=T245107|txn_amt=121.00|clnt_rqst_meta={mob:9937253528}{custname:pawan}|tpsl_txn_time=NA|tpsl_rfnd_id=NA|bal_amt=NA|rqst_token=cd3f6f55-5990-4c3b-bb12-238eede827a0|hash=3cf25909ec73865d3200bc267119d3fcc21df463';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZGwK0J/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.